# cloud 9 and sagemaker - hyper parameter optimisation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-cloud9

I have done quite a few google searches but have not found a clear answer to the following use case. Basically, I would rather use cloud 9 (most of the time) as my IDE rather than Jupyter. What I am confused/not sure about is, how I could executed long running jobs like (Bayesian) hyper parameter optimisation from there. Can I use Sagemaker capabilities? Should I use docker and deploy to ECR (looking for the cheapest-ish option)? Any pointers w.r.t. to this particular issue would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use whatever IDE you choose (including your laptop).
SaegMaker tuning job ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-ex.html)) is **asynchronous**, so you can safely close your IDE after launching it. You can [monitor the job the AWS web console,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-monitor.html) or with a [DescribeHyperParameterTuningJob API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeHyperParameterTuningJob.html).

You can launch TensorFlow, PyTorch, XGBoost, Scikit-learn, and other [popular ML frameworks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/frameworks.html), using one of the built-in framework containers, avoiding the extra work of bringing your own container.

Comment: thanks. a former colleague actually told me about this too. so this is without your own container. nice! I need to learn more about this. in addition to the inline doc, are there any good books on this you could recommend please?

Comment: Google for "SageMaker tuning jobs documentation". And visit: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/hyperparameter_tuning